# clone content tag <template> in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, clone

I'm trying to clone the contents of the tag  with jquery, but I'm unable to copy the events that are linked to child elements,
how can I do it?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `clone()` method, setting both the `withDataAndEvents` and `deepWithDataAndEvents` parameters to `true`:

```
var $templateClone = $('template').clone(true, true);
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Or alternatively, you can use the plain `clone()` method with no parameters, and use event delegation to bind your events to a common parent instead.

Comment: When used this way you spoke , it copies all the template tag , I would like to copy only the contents of the tag , to append elsewhere, I tried to use :  $('template').children().clone(true, true); and does not copy any element